# Notification count in Angular by the help of node js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

i am new in programming. I have a conceptual question.

- I have a API /getNotificationCount/{userId} to get count of any type of notification for every user. {userId} is int value. (Backend API buit in Symfony2)
- In front end i am using angular, right now i am calling /getNotificationCount/{userId} API every time(by the help of timeout function) in angular controller(ajax call) to get count.

Is there is any way to do when server hits changes(increase or decrease count) then i will get api request to get count. I searched many thing i found by the help of node js i can do this but i am unable to understand how can i start ? Can anyone please give me suggestion on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need WebSockets, have a look [here](http://socket.io/) to get started

Answer (score 0):

try to use firebase to send notification.
for server side you should use firebase admin and messaging function .
i use it in my react native front and nodeJs back project